# comma separated list oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a list of comma separated values in a single field and need to find all rows which meet a certain criteria. The code I am using is:

```
select * from table where column_name in
(
select regexp_substr('A+','A-','aabn','[^,]+', 1,level) from table
connect by regexp_substr('A+','A-','aabn', '[^,]+', 1,level) is not null
);
```

so I want to find all the rows which contain A+, A- and aabn

Comment: @arsenaaql . . . Sample data and desired results would help.  Do you need all three codes for a match?  Or will a match to any single one do?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a single regular expression?

```
where regexp_like(column_name, '(^|,)(A[+]|A[-]|aabn)($|,)')
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=da19ccaba831d1eb966ac36dd9e3869d) is a DB<>fiddle.

Also, as powerful as regular expressions are, you should not be storing multiple values in a single string.  Oracle has many other options for storing multiple values, including the traditional association/junction table.

Comment: This will not find `A+` and `A-` and `aabn` (as per the OP's requirement) it will find rows with any one of the three.

Comment: @MT0 . . . It works when I try it.  I've included a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Your code finds `A+` or `A-` or `aabn` it does not find `A+` and `A-` and `aabn` (as the OP states in the last line of their question) [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d05a26a952009a23b6f0b7dd9abb6dac)

Comment: @MT0 . . . English is ambiguous in this case.  The OP needs to clarify whether the condition is matching ANY or ALL values.

Comment: You could further simply the regex to `'(^|,)(A[+-]|aabn)($|,)'`

Comment: @Gary_W . . . Perhaps `A[-+]` rather than `A[+-]`.

Comment: It makes no difference whether it is `[-+]` or `[+-]` as Oracle will treat the [dash character as a literal](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/B14251_01/adfns_regexp.htm#r9c1-t7) when it occurs first or last in the list or as the ending range point of a range expression.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regular expressions, just use `LIKE` to check that the value you require is a sub-string of the column (both surrounded by delimiter characters):

If you want all 3 in the list then use `AND`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  ',' || column_name || ',' LIKE '%,A+,%'
AND    ',' || column_name || ',' LIKE '%,A-,%'
AND    ',' || column_name || ',' LIKE '%,aabn,%'
```

If you want any 1 in the list then use `OR`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  ',' || column_name || ',' LIKE '%,A+,%'
OR     ',' || column_name || ',' LIKE '%,A-,%'
OR     ',' || column_name || ',' LIKE '%,aabn,%'
```